# Java: using string wildcards/regex as the key of a map

Tags: java, regex, string, dictionary, wildcard

I have a small java project which tries to match a given customer record with one in a database based on closest match.

A given customer has a unique combination of String variables-
Name, Address1, Address2

If some data is missing then the default for a given variable is "ALL".

The code retrieves all the database records and creates a **map** of customer records where customerKey is a unique combination of name, address1, address2.
CustomerKey is a class of these string variables with their own getters/setters and hashcode (from apache HashCodeBuilder).

CustomerData is just a dump of all the data in the record for that customer in the database

The code works as normal so far

```
String name = "Harry"; 
String address1 = "hello street"; 
String address2 = "hello town";

map<customerKey, CustomerData> lookupMap = getDataFromDB();

CustomerData data = lookupMap.get(new CustomerKey(name, address1, address2));

if (data==null){ 
data = lookupMap.get(new CustomerKey("ALL", address1, address2)); 
} 

if (data==null){ 
data = lookupMap.get(new CustomerKey("ALL", "ALL", address2)); 
} 

if (data==null){ 
data = lookupMap.get(new CustomerKey("ALL", "ALL", "ALL")); 
} 

return data
```

I want to be able to add wildcards to the matching process where it is applied to the names. I can find out the regex for what i want e.g. **.*arry**  and add that to the name of a particular record.

And i know that if i want to use wild card comparisons of strings then i need to use **.matches** rather than **.equals** (e.g. **"harry".matches(".*arry")**.

But i'm having some difficulty moving forward from there.

Does anyone have some advice?

Comment: = means assignment and == means check for equal. Overall I think you need to improve the code you posted like `if` instead of `If` and other misuse of lowercase/upercase and use the indentation I edited etc

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry yes, i meant == and if

Comment: You could perhaps use `contains()` or read up on some basic regex like ".*arry$" to get any string ending with "arry"